# Unable to control a variable in a loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I can't seem to understand why this part of code doesn't work, despite it being very straightforward. The program supposed to do this, 1. Input: ask the user to insert a number (value is stored in height), 2. Output: The program will then return " " (spaces) which decrements in each rows.

This is the example of the outcome I want: (I use F instead of spaces)

input: 4

output:

FFFF
FFF
FF
F

this is what I'm getting:

input: 4

output:

FFFF
FFFF
FFFF
FFFF

```
        for (int r = 0; r <= height; r++)        // first loop, does the columns
      { int space = height;

        space -= 1;                             // decrements space value by 1 for each loop

        while (space != 0)                      // list out the correct spaces in each row
        {   
                                  
            printf (" ");
            space--;    
        }
```

Comment: First of all please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. Secondly I recommend you learn some common debugging techniques, like for example [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and also use an actual debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That should help you understand what happens.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback friend! Yes I also agree that my questions are unproductive, I really thought that adding examples would make my question more readable, I will do better next time. I will definitely learn more about debugging thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the for loop

```
    for (int r = 0; r <= height; r++)        // first loop, does the columns
  { int space = height;

    space -= 1;                             // decrements space value by 1 for each loop

    while (space != 0)                      // list out the correct spaces in each row
    {   
                              
        printf (" ");
        space--;    
    }
```

the variable space is always set to the same value `height - 1`

```
     int space = height;

    space -= 1;
```

You can output the pattern you showed the following way

```
for ( ; 0 < height; --height )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        putchar( 'F' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the outer loop you reinitialize `space` to `height`, so you get the same output on each iteration.

An easier approach would be to use the loop variable as the number of columns and iterate over it *backwards*:

```
for (int r = height; r > 0 ; r--)
{
    for (int space = 0; space < r; ++space)
    {
        printf("F");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```